# ActiveModel serializers under namespace not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I have below serializer /serializers/api/club_serializer.rb:

```
class Api::ClubSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  cached
  attributes :id, :name, :created_at
end
```

And below method under /controllers/api/clubs_controller.rb

```
module Api

  class ClubsController < BaseController
    include ActionController::ImplicitRender
    include ActionController::MimeResponds

    # GET /clubs
    def index
      @clubs = Club.all
      render json: @clubs, serializer: ClubSerializer
    end
```

This doesn't seem to be working properly as I remove name it still shows name with all fields.

How do I change it so it works?

Comment: Maybe pass the serializer as a constant, not a symbol?

Comment: @avlazarov Yes I changed it but it still does not seem to work. It's still showing name field

Comment: But you don't get an error, like `Unable to autoload constant ClubSerializer`?

Comment: Exactly as JTG says - tried every permutation of everything.  the old syntax gives you the same error as the suggested.  Also tried serializer versions from .09 to .1rc4 - no help.  You can take out the 'api' bit from the serializer's class def, and it will run a 'puts' in there, but doesn't actually 'do' anything - you just get all the model's columns, and still without the virutal_attrs.  Evidently, serializer is not designed to for APIs.  I guess just another "hobby" project of no practical use.

Comment: @JosephK Curious if you guys found a solution to this? Same boat..

Comment: @geoboy - no, I abandoned it, since it didn't work, and wound up doing some manual fix to get the results desired.  Not sure if newer versions ever fixed the problem, as I never tried it again after v 0.1rc4.

Answer (score 2):

The way you do this now:

```
render json: @clubs, namespace: Api
```

See: https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/general/rendering.md#namespace

Comment: This worked for me, could not figure out why my namespaced serializers were serializing differently in production (this was due to eager loading)

Answer (score 1):

why not:

```
render json: @clubs, each_serializer: ::Api::ClubSerializer
```

Comment: does serializer file need to be under specific folder structure?

Comment: No your file structure is fine. Notice I replaced your `serializer` key with `each_serializer`

Comment: @apneadiving In general, you never need `each_serializer`. I wonder if you can do without it with namespacing?

Comment: @geoboy in general, the serializer is guessed based on class name. I do prefer the code to be explicit so I alway specify it. Matter of taste :)